# VirtualBox: OpenGL version limited to OpenGL 2.1

Tags: ubuntu, opengl, virtualbox

my computer is running on windows 7 with **OpenGL 4.5**. The graphic card is an ATI HD 5470. When I launch my virtual machine (Ubuntu 15.10 32-bit) with VirtualBox and the guest additions installed:

-enabling 3d acceleration, I can only use **OpenGL 2.1**

-disabling 3d acceleration, I can only use **OpenGL 3.0**

I need to have my virtual machine using **at least OpenGL 3.2**, because I am trying to compile geometry shaders. How can I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found a solution. The OpenGL caps are fine for the driver, but as Bas Nieuwenhuizen said, it is possible to use a core profile. In my case, the program I tried to run could be compiled with an option allowing the use of core profiles, however, a problem in the guest additions of VirtualBox with Ubuntu 15.10 was provoking the following message when running an OpenGL program, say glxinfo:

`libGL error: core dri or dri2 extension not found`

The problem has been reported a while back with [this ticket](https://www.virtualbox.org/ticket/12941) and a temporary build on bottom of the page fixes the problem. I'm not entirely satisfied with the result, but that worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

For software only it should be possible to get 3.3 using a core profile, as mesa supports > 3.0 only for the core profile.

Maybe you need to compile a new mesa (http://cgit.freedesktop.org/mesa/mesa)  version from git if the Ubuntu package is too old.

There is a repository that provides very recent packages for Ubuntu: https://launchpad.net/~oibaf/+archive/ubuntu/graphics-drivers

I have no idea how to get GL3+ with hardware acceleration, though.

Comment: I wasn't aware of this whole core profile story so your answer helped me a lot. I still got the problem, though, and trying to get some informations about the core profiles with glxinfo shows me this: "libGL error: core dri or dri2 extension not found". I'm also having an existential crisis about whether or not I should accept the answer

Comment: Do you use the environment variable LIBGL_ALWAYS_SOFTWARE=1 for 3d acceleration disabled? If you do not can you try it. If that does not work i have no clue what the problem is.

Comment: That didn't change a thing, but I found out this was just a recurring bug in VirtualBox. Thank you for your propositions anyway!